# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_getAssertEqualityFunc' when trying to make a wrapper around assertEquals

Tags: python, selenium, assert

I am trying to make a wrapper method around assertEquals (code below). When i run the tests I receive the following error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_getAssertEqualityFunc'"

I have tried using directly assertEquals and it works but I need to do more stuff when an assert fails.

```
from unittest import TestCase as a


class Asserts:

    _assert_list = []

    @property
    def assert_list(self):
       return self._assert_list

    def equals(self, first, second, msg=None):
        """Fail if the two objects are unequal as determined by the '=='
           operator.
        """
        try:
            A.assertEquals(first, second, msg)

        except AssertionError:
            self._assert_list.append(AssertionError.__cause__)
```

Edit: changed the code a bit.
I want to use this when performing multiple tests to not stop in the middle of the run if something fails along the way. Like make all these asserts that in stead of stopping the test if one fails, it appends the cause to the list and at the finish i will assert if the list is empty or not.

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path", line 88, in test_tc_01
    self.a.equals(self.li, self.li2)
File "path", line 21, in equals
    a.assertEquals(first, second, msg)
File "path, line 1321, in deprecated_func
    return original_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "path", line 828, in assertEqual
    assertion_func = self._getAssertEqualityFunc(first, second) 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_getAssertEqualityFunc'

EDIT 2: I have multiple asserts in one test. If, for example, the first fails, the rest of them are skipped. This is why i want to implement this in my framework

EDIT 3: at request, putting here a test

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = WebDriver(browser='chrome').browser
    self.driver.get(self.RLO_URL)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.a = Asserts()

    login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
    login_page.log_in()

def test_tc_01(self):
    self.maxDiff = None
    nav_page = NavBarPage(self.driver)
    nav_page.go_to_start_new_process()

    start_new_process_page = StartNewProcessPage(self.driver)
    start_new_process_page.start()

    process_page = ProcessPage(self.driver)
    app_info = process_page.application_info
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    # self.assertEquals(app_info.get_country_list(), self.EXPECTED_COUNTRIES)
    self.assertEquals(app_info.get_channel_list(), self.EXPECTED_CHANNELS)
    self.assertEquals(app_info.get_marketing_source_list(), self.EXPECTED_MARKETING_SOURCE)
    self.assertEquals(app_info.get_marketing_agreement_list(), self.EXPECTED_MARKETING_AGREEMENT)
    self.assertEquals(app_info.get_office_credit_list(), self.EXPECTED_OFFICE_CREDIT)

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: This really isn't how you write Python. What's the point of the property? Why use double-underscore prefix? Why define a setter instead of just appending to the list? But more importantly, you need to show some example of how you use this and the full traceback.

Comment: Thank you. I am very new to this and am still learning along the way. I have edited the question. See the added text below the code block

Comment: I think you better of telling us what you are trying to accomplish, there is probably a better way to do it than writing assertions on your own

Comment: Just saw you did write what your trying to accomplish. If you follow unittest formatting, one failed test will not fail the whole suite. your all good

Comment: @Rafi, yes but a test case has 5 points of verification and for that test case i have made a class that has a method test_tc_01 which has 5 assertions. one for each verification point. If the first assertion fails. The rest of the asserts will be skipped

Comment: Sounds like a bad testing design. If you'r willing to share your code, we can try to help you. If you want a quickfix (that is dirty), use regular assert and wrap it with a try and catch

Comment: That is the dirty fix i want to implement. I know that the way i am making it right now is not the way it should be made but not my saying in this... Trying to wrap it in a try catch (example in question) i receive that error message and i don't know what to do because if i don't use the wrapper it works fine... and i cannot share code due to proxy :/

Answer (score -1):

I took an example from the unittest documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), and added a failing test in the middle (asserted that false is true just to for showing you this).

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_fail(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When you run this you will get the following output:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_fail (__main__.TestStringMethods)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/refael.cohen/PycharmProjects/tools & trials/unittest_suite.py", line 13, in test_fail
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Note that even though the suite failed, all the tests ran.

Also, you can use `@unittest.expectedFailure` decorator to expect the test to fail, and then the whole suite will pass

Comment: yes but I have to verify multiple elements in a page. If i define multiple tests it means i would have to perform the login for each element, and there are a lot of elements...

Comment: if you try to find an element and its not there, the driver will fail, thus meaning you can not continue. you can use the find_elements method instead of find_element which returns an empty list if no element is found and then just check if that list is empty, thus the element wat not found.

Comment: Like I said in the previous comment, without a driver, you can not continue the interaction with the page. I think you should try using selenium methods that dont fail if they dont find the elements, like `is_displayed` or `is_clickable` or `find_elemnts`

Comment: I have to verify the contents of multiple dropdown lists, and the names of multiple sections in a page...

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem? simply store the list of elements in a variable, and if its empty, store a boolean flag saying that this specific element was not found. do so to all the elements, then print/log/fail according to these boolean flags.

Comment: i just want to know why doesn't the code I wrote above working... I cannot create multiple tests for all the asserts as it is imposed on me....